# How to make input field for flatpickr is required?

Tags: html, jquery, flatpickr

I have tried to apply some logic jQuery validation but it is not working. Anyone can help to ensure user need to fill up both fields before able to proceed with next action?

What I am getting right now if the field is empty, its looks like not null or undefined. I don't what is the value at console as below.

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center" id="startEndDateForm">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDateMain" placeholder="Start Date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDateMain" placeholder="End Date">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="btnCheckDate"><i class="mdi mdi-magnify"></i></span> // This is the submit button, I am using icon
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#startDateMain, #endDateMain").flatpickr({
    enableTime: true,
    altInput: true,
    dateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
    altFormat: "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss",
    minuteIncrement: 1,
    allowInput: true
});

$("#btnCheckDate").on("click", function(){
    var checkFieldValue = true;
    var startDate = $("#startDateMain").val();
    var endDate = $("#endDateMain").val();
    if (startDate == null || startDate == "") {
        checkFieldValue = false;
    }
    if (endDate == null || endDate == "") {
        checkFieldValue = false;
    }
    if (checkFieldValue){
        console.log('Success');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeof` operator to check the type of value in this case, like:

```js
console.log(typeof startDate)
```

But an even more useful tool is to use your browser's debugger. This gives you insight into your code, and you can see the values of variables as your code runs. We can set a breakpoint in your code to "pause" execution so you can inspect the variables. For simplicity's sake in this answer, we can use the `debugger` statement to trigger a pause. You can then see the values of `startDate` and `endDate` in your code:

```js
$("#startDateMain, #endDateMain").flatpickr({
    enableTime: true,
    altInput: true,
    dateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
    altFormat: "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss",
    minuteIncrement: 1,
    allowInput: true
});

$("#btnCheckDate").on("click", function(){
    var checkFieldValue = true;
    var startDate = $("#startDateMain").val();
    var endDate = $("#endDateMain").val();
    debugger;
    if (startDate == null || startDate == "") {
        checkFieldValue = false;
    }
    if (endDate == null || endDate == "") {
        checkFieldValue = false;
    }
    if (checkFieldValue){
        console.log('Success');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center" id="startEndDateForm">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDateMain" placeholder="Start Date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDateMain" placeholder="End Date">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="btnCheckDate"><i class="mdi mdi-magnify">click</i></span> // This is the submit button, I am using icon
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I debugged the code, the empty values of `startDate` and `endDate` values when empty were empty strings.

As another note, you could simplify your `if` statements to just check for [falsey values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), since I don't believe any falsey values are useful in this context:

```js
if (!startDate) {
    checkFieldValue = false;
}
if (!endDate) {
    checkFieldValue = false;
}
```

and this can simplify further down into:

```js
// If either value is falsey, checkFieldValue will be false.
checkFieldValue = startDate && checkFieldValue;
```